# Ruby on Rails: Cannot add pagination both [Kaminari or will_paginate] to categorized posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination

I've been having issues in getting any pagination to work on categorized posts. For example, the index where all the posts are, pagination works but as a soon as I click the category I get an error like this.

What am I doing wrong?

```
undefined method `total_pages' for #<Post::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f60061f5f78>
```

Posts Controller with Kaminari

```
def index
    if 
        params[:category].blank?
        @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per(1)
    else
        @category_id = Category.all 
        @category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id
        @posts = Post.where(category_id: @category_id).order("created_at DESC")
    end
end
```

Posts Controller with will_paginate

```
 def index
        if 
            params[:category].blank?
            @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC").paginate(page:params[:page], per_page: 1 )
        else
            @category_id = Category.all 
            @category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id
            @posts = Post.where(category_id: @category_id).order("created_at DESC")
        end
    end
```

View:

```
<%= paginate @posts %>
```

View:

```
<%= will_paginate @posts %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `page` or `paginate` method for `@posts` in else part in controller,

```
def index
    if 
        params[:category].blank?
        @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC").paginate(page:params[:page], per_page: 1 )
    else
        @category_id = Category.all 
        @category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id
        @posts = Post.where(category_id: @category_id).order("created_at DESC").paginate(page:params[:page], per_page: 1 )
    end
end
```

Comment: I'm still new, but how do I go about doing that? Do you mean `def page
        @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC").paginate(page:params[:page], per_page: 1 )
    end`?